# spring batch flow control (My step has all completed but job drops fail status)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

Hi i'm using spring batch to make some batch product but my logic doesn't work.
I want to know why!
Please give some answer

My logic is like this

```java
public test_job(){
   return jobBuilderFactory.get("test_job").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer()).preventRestart()
          .start(fileCollectTasklet())
             .on("FAILED")
             .to(writerTasklet())
             .on("*")
             .fail()
          .from(fileCollectTasklet())
             .on("FAILED")
             .to(writerTasklet())
             .on("*")
             .end()
          .end()
}
```

I want to make if fileCollectTasklet() finished with FAILED, then run writerTasklet and make end job with fail status doesn't matter how writerTasklet end.
And if fileCollectTasklet() finished with COMPLETE, then run writerTasklet and make end job with SUCESS status doesn't matter how writerTasklet end.

Could you guys help me????

Answer (score 1):

1. Start with `fileCollectTasklet()`.
2. If `fileCollectTasklet()` fails (`on("FAILED")`), run `writerTasklet()` and fail the job regardless of the outcome of `writerTasklet()` (`.on("*").fail()`).
3. If `fileCollectTasklet()` finishes with any other status, run `writerTasklet()` and complete the job regardless of the outcome of `writerTasklet()` (`.on("*").end()`).

```
public Job testJob() {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("test_job")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .preventRestart()
            .start(fileCollectTasklet())
                .on("FAILED")
                .to(writerTasklet()).on("*").fail()
            .from(fileCollectTasklet())
                .on("*")
                .to(writerTasklet())
                .on("*")
                .end()
            .end();
}
```